# Best server-side technology for a mobile web app

Tags: mobile, web-applications, frameworks

I'm about to develop a web app for mobile devices and I'm wondering which server-side technology to choose. I have a strong experience with backend and frontend use of PHP (MySQL and others), but I make an educated guess that choosing this combination wouldn't be the best choice for scalability.

I've heard great things about Ruby, but my mind is fixated on Node.js, probably just because I like the idea of using the same language on the server and on the client. Just knowing the best weather app is a web app (http://forecast.io) makes me believe in the web more than ever before so I'm not going to learn any software coding for now.

Also, I have a lot of ease with learning a new language so that doesn't scare me. I just need a bunch of tutorials and examples to sniff from and I'd be good to go.

So, to structure my question, I'm asking for your recommendations on :

1. Server technology (Cloud hosting, which one? At what level of usage do you really need cloud scalability?
2. Server language (Node, Ruby, PHP, others?)
3. Server framework and/or ORM?
4. Database storage (I need geolocation features, I would guess Postgre?)
5. Front-end framework?

Thank you in advance for you help!